# Bluetooth reboots ESP32 when connecting

Tags: bluetooth, iot, microcontroller, esp32

I've tried running an old application of mine on an ESP32 micro controller and I kept getting errors such as

> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)

or

> CORRUPT HEAP: Bad head at 0x3ffd8c18. Expected 0xabba1234 got 0xbaad5678

or

> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

on all of my boards when attempting to use Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there has been an update in ESP32-Arduino.

Changing

```
platform = espressif32
```

to

```
platform = espressif32@3.5.0
```

solved my issue.