# rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) - bluetooth Reboots

Tags: c++, bluetooth, esp32, arduino-esp32, platformio

so I have a strange problem using `arduino-esp32` Bluetooth library. here is the [link](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial) of the library. **note that** for some reason they didn't provide any documentation for their library but only code examples.

so one of their code examples which was [this example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial/examples/SerialToSerialBT/SerialToSerialBT.ino):

```
//This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)
//By Evandro Copercini - 2018
//
//This example creates a bridge between Serial and Classical Bluetooth (SPP)
//and also demonstrate that SerialBT have the same functionalities of a normal Serial

#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

//#define USE_PIN // Uncomment this to use PIN during pairing. The pin is specified on the line below
const char *pin = "1234"; // Change this to more secure PIN.

String device_name = "ESP32-BT-Slave";

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_SPP_ENABLED)
#error Serial Bluetooth not available or not enabled. It is only available for the ESP32 chip.
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin(device_name); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.printf("The device with name \"%s\" is started.\nNow you can pair it with Bluetooth!\n", device_name.c_str());
  //Serial.printf("The device with name \"%s\" and MAC address %s is started.\nNow you can pair it with Bluetooth!\n", device_name.c_str(), SerialBT.getMacString()); // Use this after the MAC method is implemented
  #ifdef USE_PIN
    SerialBT.setPin(pin);
    Serial.println("Using PIN");
  #endif
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

and it worked perfectly, so I wanted to organize code into classes and customize my usage for this libraries into separate classes.

so I write the code in this fashion:

### bluetooth.h

```
/*library link: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial*/
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"


class Bluetooth
{
private:

    /*this is object used to access bluetooth utils*/
    BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

public:


    /*this is the name of the esp32 when being searched for*/
    const String device_name = "ESP32-Carcotech";

    /*this is the Pin number for connection with ESP for legacy devices*/
    const char *pin = "1234";

    /*constructor*/
    Bluetooth();
  
    /*destructor*/
    ~Bluetooth();

    /**
     * @brief used to receive a string from the bluetooth
     * @param dataLen: is the length of the expected data to receive from the bluetooth module
     * @param timeOutMS: is the timeOut to wait for if not all data received : put 0 to wait infinitely if didn't till recevie same dataLen
    */
    String getData(int dataLen, uint32_t timeOutMS);

    /**
     * @brief used to send data over the bluetooth module
     * @param data: this is the data to send
    */
    void sendData(String data);

};
```

### bluetooth.cpp

```
#include "bluetooth.h"



Bluetooth::Bluetooth()
{

    // initialization of the bluetooth
    SerialBT.begin(device_name);

    // telling the bluetooth to use that pin for connection
    SerialBT.setPin(pin);

}

String Bluetooth::getData(int dataLen, uint32_t timeOutMS)
{
    // this is a counter for how many data we received
    int receivedCounter = 0;

    // this is the buffer to receive in
    String data;

    // setting the timeOut
    //SerialBT.setTimeout(timeOutMS);     

    // check if we should wait indefinitely or not
    if(timeOutMS == 0)
    {
        while(SerialBT.available())
        {
            if(receivedCounter == dataLen)
                break;
            
            data += SerialBT.read();
            receivedCounter++;
        }
        
    }
    else
    {

        while(SerialBT.available())
        {
            int temp = SerialBT.read();

            if(receivedCounter == dataLen || temp == -1 )
                break;
            
            data += SerialBT.read();
            receivedCounter++;
        }

    }

    return data + "\0";
}

void Bluetooth::sendData(String data)
{
    SerialBT.write((const uint8_t *)data.c_str(), strlen(data.c_str()));
}


Bluetooth::~Bluetooth()
{
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include "bluetooth.h"

Bluetooth bluetooth;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  /*Serial.println(bluetooth.getData(10, 0));
  delay(1000);
  bluetooth.sendData("A");*/
}
```

but I repeatedly got this message in the terminal and the bluetooth on esp32 doesn't work:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
```

seems like for some reason it's using **RTC** to reset itself again and again and again,...

I found some other one with the same problem here in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73040474/bluetooth-reboots-esp32-when-connecting).

he said only to update `espressif32` to `espressif32@3.5.0` in the **init** file.

and I did so but no change, here is my init file:

```
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32@3.5.0
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

I guess the problem is with my C++ code style, so I think it's code style problem not a problem with hardware as code example provided in library.

Comment: Did not focus too much on this, but typically you might want to avoid endless loops which don't yield the current task. Try adding something like `vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));` into each loop iteration. Also you should see a stack trace with detailed reason for the reboot right before `rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)` appears. If it's too sparse to understand, you can feed it into a tool like [EspExceptionDecoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) to see a human-readable version.

Comment: A side note, your .h file should have header guards.

Comment: Try add `yield();` or `delay(1);` to the two `while` loops in your `Bluetooth::getData()` method.

Comment: @Tarmo, your suggestion really helped me, but can you elaborate on why I should introduce `vTaskDelay()` in the loops (it worked but I still don't understand why)

Comment: In embedded SW every task needs to periodically report that it is still operational and not blocked by an endless loop, deadlock or other critical SW bug. When such a bug triggers, the SW task fails to report in time and a hardware module called watchdog will reset the system to bring it back to a operational state. In other systems you typically need to reset the watchdog timer explicitly, but on ESP IDF a service does it for you if you simply yield the current task: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/wdts.html#task-watchdog-timer-twdt

Answer (score 1):

so for some reason (I really wish if I could know why) but all what I did is to move the initialization code from the constructor to a custom function called `init` , so instead of :

```
Bluetooth::Bluetooth()
{

    // initialization of the bluetooth
    SerialBT.begin(device_name);

    // telling the bluetooth to use that pin for connection
    SerialBT.setPin(pin);

}
```

all what I did is :

```
Bluetooth::Bluetooth()
{


}

void Bluetooth::init()
{
    
    // initialization of the bluetooth
    SerialBT.begin(device_name);

    // telling the bluetooth to use that pin for connection
    SerialBT.setPin(pin);
}
```

and the `init` function is called from the `setup()` function in `main.cpp` (writing `bluetooth.init()` at the beginning of `setup()` ) and it worked for some reason.

**EDIT**: someone on reddit said

> "It worked because the constructor gets called before the rest of the
> Arduino initialization code, and the `begin()` gets called in `setup()`
> after internal Arduino core init"